# Can We execute an exe that is in client side?

Tags: client, executable

Is there any way to execute exe(say notepad.exe) that is in client? If so.. how can i do that from server side.? I know its a security violation..still i want to know.

Comment: It's not really good practice to add a "belongs-on-X" tag to a question. It will cause problems when the question is eventually migrated. Better to add a comment or if you think it's particularly urgent flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Yeah... that's a huge security violation. I don't know of any way you can do that, and I hope there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to do this:

1. Via a security loophole in your system; which should be patched up as soon as possible.
2. Via a mechanism such as click-once, which requires the user to confirm that they want to download the application and run it.